# read data from file to an array

Tags: c++, file-io

I have the following data written on a file. I want to neglect all the zeros in the beginning and the but the starting from 181 in an array each number in a cell so I could use it easily.

I know how to put data in an array but how could I neglect all these zeros ??

0 177 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 181 98 1 2 28 0 104 93 165 3 7 110 239 5 172 164 176 29 56 147 4 0 234 215 3 0 166 6 0 0 78 5 0 0 164 145 181 98 1 2 28 0 80 97 165 3 7 110 239 5 172 164 176 29 56 147 4 0 234 215 3 0 169 6 0 0 78 5 0 0 147 117 181 98 1 2 28 0 56 101 165 3 7 110 239 5 172 164 176 29 56 147 4 0 234 215 3 0 173 6 0 0 81 5 0 0 134 109 181 98 1 2 28 0 32 105 165 3 7 110 239 5 172 164 176 29 56 147 4 0 234 215 3 0 181 6 0 0 85 5 0 0 126 137 181 98 1 2 28 0 8 109 165 3 7 110 239 5 172 164 176 29 56 147 4 0 234 215 3 0 182 6 0 0 87 5 0 0 109 101

Comment: What about the 177 near the beginning?

Comment: No I don't need it also the device just sends random data until it gets its signal correctly

Comment: How do you know that 177 is not meaningful, but 181 is?

Comment: hmmm... what is the rule for ignoring the `177` ?

Comment: the message that I get always starts with 181 98 that is in the data sheet of the GPS I am using if you look carefully you will find that 181 98 1 2 28 is repeated alot.

Comment: Have you attempted to code a solution? If so, please update.

Comment: So the actual requirement is to ignore everything until the sequence 181 98 is found?

Comment: Whats the protocol? Is somewhere the size of the packet specified or is the end marked by another sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, so I will post multiple answers. Choose the one that fits with your problem's description.

**Case 1:** ignore everything before(or before and including) `181`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("input.txt");
  std::vector<int> vec;
  int reached_181 = 0, x;

  while(in >> x) {
    if(x == 181) reached_181 = 1;
    if(reached_181) vec.push_back(x);
    // if you also want to neglect 181 then just change the order of the two commands
    // if(reached_181) vec.push_back(x);
    // if(x == 181) reached_181 = 1;
  }

  for(std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Case 2:** ignore every *zero* before `181`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("input.txt");
  std::vector<int> vec;
  int reached_181 = 0, x;

  while(in >> x) {
    if(x == 181) reached_181 = 1;
    if(reached_181 || x) vec.push_back(x);
  }

  for(std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Case 3:** ignore all the zeroes in the input file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream in("input.txt");
  std::vector<int> vec;
  int x;

  while(in >> x) {
    if(x) vec.push_back(x);
  }

  for(std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::fstream out("out.txt"); // name of your file
    bool hit;

    for (int n; (out >> n);)
    {
        if (n == 181 && !hit)
            hit = true;
        if (!hit)
            if (n)
                v.push_back(n);

        if (hit)
            v.push_back(n);
    }

    typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter_type;

    for (iter_type it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: That ignores all 0 values, not only those before the 181. If I understood it correctly, the later 0 values are significant.

Comment: I've been trying it for quiet a time and I can't solve the error the compiler doesn't recognize it what does an auto mean ?

Comment: @ZeyadSerag Oh, `auto` just means that the type of the object will be deduced automatically. That is a C++11 feature (something I'm now finding out your compiler doesn't support). Use `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` instead. I will update.

Comment: @ZeyadSerag Oh, I thought you wanted to get rid of *all* the 0s. Okay, I will update again.